# Replacement for "narrowly missed?"

Tags: adverbs

I am trying to remove adverbs from my writing.

> My grant proposal narrowly missed the funding threshold.

I want to replace the phrase "narrowly missed" **or change the whole sentence** but still imply how close I was.

Comment: To 'come up short' (yes, I know that's an adverb) often means to 'miss by a narrow margin' (which phrase contains no adverbs, but I don't know if your prejudice extends to them). You can also try rewriting the sentence rather than just try to plug in a different word.

Comment: oh yeah, I should have specified that rewriting the sentence is fine as long as it conveys the same idea.

Answer (score 4):

I think that [undershoot](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/undershoot) may be a useful expression in your contest.

Literally (from TFD)

> - to shoot short of or below (a target)

It is also often in a [figurative](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/undershoot) sense especially in a financial context.

> - to fail to achieve a particular result:
>     undershoot sth by sth
>
>   - The finance minister undershot his forecast by €3 billion.

(from dictionary.cambridge.org)

The idea is that of missing a possible target. You need an adverb to define the magnitude, but I think the expression conveys the idea effectively.

Comment: I considered *undershoot* too, but as you yourself point out, it lacks the connotation of a shortfall that is only slightly off. That is well demonstrated by your second citation, "...undershot his forecast by €3 billion".

Comment: @ErikKowal-   Both our suggestions need an adverb to define how much the target has been missed. Can't think of a single word either.

Comment: right, its connotation is no more or less strong than "missed".

Comment: @japreiss - It is closer to your desired meaning than 'missed', because it does at least indicate a *shortfall*, whereas you can also *miss* by *overshooting*.

Comment: @ErikKowal true, but they are equal in this context because if I overshot the funding threshold I would be writing about how successful my grant proposal was :)

Answer (score 3):

You could say:

> My grant proposal **fell [just] short of** the funding threshold.

Note that in this context, the word 'just' (enclosed by square brackets above) is an adverb. I have included it in the alternative wording because it contributes to the sense of nearly-but-not-quite, but you can omit it if you are determined to exclude adverbs.

You could also reword the sentence to give it a positive sense instead:

> My grant proposal **almost reached / almost achieved** the funding threshold.

'Almost' is an adverb too, but I suspect that many people would not recognize it as such because it doesn't end in the *-ly* that is typical of so many adverbs.

The shortcomings of my wordings reflect a fundamental difficulty with what you are trying to do. This is that English relies quite heavily on modifying verbs with adverbs in order to generate different degrees of emphasis and shades of meaning — something that many other languages achieve by attaching different prefixes and/or suffixes to the verb stem.

**Edit**

The OP has now changed the wording of the question to accept complete rewrites of the sentence. In which case, something along the lines of

> My grant proposal missed the funding threshold **by a narrow margin** / **by a small amount**

should do the job.

Comment: Wow. Is there no single word that means "narrowly missed", then?

Comment: @ZayneSHalsall - I can't think of one, otherwise I would have mentioned it. But I'm willing to be proved wrong.

Comment: Do 'fall short of, reach or achieve' have connotations that indicate a narrower gap the 'undershoot'?

Comment: @Josh61 - I think 'fall short of' does, at least to my ear. But it's rather subjective — others may well disagree. 'Reached' and 'achieved' really do need the 'almost' to generate the desired nuance. In my opinion, there is no fully satisfactory answer to the original version of the OP's question.